# does JDK uses HashTable

Tags: java, hashtable

Hi I was going through the comparison between HashTable and other collection classes. I wanted to know if any of the Java JDK API uses HashTable. I have seen many discussion here about the HashTable but did not find any usecase for it within JDK.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can see uses of `Hashtable`:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/class-use/Hashtable.html

Some of the packages listed that use the Hashtable:

```
java.awt    
java.security   
java.util   
javax.management    
javax.naming     
javax.swing
```

Comment: Thanks, this is used more often than I thought. Even Java RMI is still using it. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: The whole of JNDI still uses it.